# Get the first 13 bit from short

Tags: c#

I have byte array

```
byte[] PixelData = {255,235};
```

I want to convert it to short and before that I want to get the first 13 bit before the conversion because when I convert using the following code improper values return

```
short val1 = 0;
val1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(PixelData, 0);
```

any ideas how to do that

Comment: what number do you want `{255,235}` with 13 bits to be? what is the desired result? there are a number of ways of interpreting that data - big/little endian? 13 msb/lsb? etc

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this is an endianness issue. If unsure, use shifting instead:

```
short val1 = (short) ((PixelData[0] << 8) | (PixelData[1]));
```

if you really need the 13 bits, use an `&` mask:

```
short val1 = (short) (((PixelData[0] << 8) | (PixelData[1])) & 8191);
```

Note: I've assumed big-endian in the above; if your data is little-endian, just reverse them:

```
short val1 = (short) ((PixelData[0]) | (PixelData[1] << 8));
```

and

```
short val1 = (short) (((PixelData[0]) | (PixelData[1] << 8)) & 8191);
```

Comment: @AMH 8191 is the decimal representation of the binary "1111111111111" (i.e. 13 x "1"), which restricts the answer to the 13 least significant bits

Comment: @AMH if you had mentioned what you **expect** `{255,235}` to  result in, I could be more specific

Comment: for array {0,28} the short val1 = (short) (((PixelData[0] << 8) | (PixelData[1])) & 8191); is 28, any idea

Comment: @AMH and... what do you expect it to be? and why? this information is necessary in order to describe the **correct** endiannesss and masking

Comment: {255,235} should return  -1024

Comment: @AMH -1024 is, in binary (using big-endian octets, shown as nibbles), "1111 1100 0000 0000" - not sure how you are constructing that from 255 ("1111 1111") and 235 ("1110 1011") - please explain how -1024 relates to {255,235}

Comment: I say short val1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(PixelData, 0) ; then check  if (val1 > Convert.ToInt16(Math.Pow(2, 13)))
                    {

                        val1 = (short)(val1 - Convert.ToInt16(Math.Pow(2, 13)));

                    }

Comment: @AMH well, the first thing I'd observe is that using `>` with arbitrary binary is deadly - the MSB could be 1, which breaks that (unless you use `ushort`). Likewise, mathematical subtraction (`-`) is  probably wrong here. What is it you are trying to **do** here? and why? I believe the error is in your logic, hence I need to understand the logic... When dealing with binary data, it is far more normal to use **bitwise** arithmetic, since that is a: faster, and b: doesn't go crazy when the MSB is set. Also, the `-` would only work if **all** the bits are set, which is not a pre-condition of `>`

Comment: @AMH so to repeat; the *math* work (`>` and `-`) is **how** you are trying to do "something"; I want to know: what **is** the "something", because I strongly suspect the current "how" is incorrect. Tell me what the "something" is, and I can surely guide you to a working alternative "how"

Comment: Bits.Converttoint16 it convert {255,235} to -5121

Comment: @AMH which is exactly what we get if use use little-endian shifting without a mask, i.e. the 3rd example in my post (`short val1 = (short) ((PixelData[0]) | (PixelData[1] << 8));`). And?